# sorting json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of locations that I am turning into Json.. I need to sort these locations by distance after I turn it into a Json list.

I am traversing through the list and adding each location to an array like so

```
locations = []

    for location in data:
        filtered_string = {'distance': location['distance']}
        locations.append(filtered_string)
```

I am then trying to sort them like this:

```
 sorted(locations,key=extract_distance, reverse=True)

def extract_distance(json):
    try:
        return int(json['distance'])
    except KeyError:
        return 0
```

Comment: That looks reasonable - where are you having problems? (Except that I don't see any actual JSON anywhere)

Comment: So do you need to sort them by distance after or before you convert it to json?
What is the actual question? There does not seem to be any.

Comment: Are you not saving the results of `sorted(...)` to a variable? `sorted()` returns a new list while `a_list.sort()` sorts in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sorted(locations, key=lambda k: k['distance'], reverse=True)
```

if you want the original data intact instead of separating just distances and assuming that data also has key distance (which seems to be the case as you are using location['distance'])

```
sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['distance'], reverse=True)
```